# Background image being replaced by empty background in Android

Tags: android

I have an android app which first screen is a login form that has a blue background image.

My problem is that in some devices like a **LG G2**, the blue image appears for an instant and the it gets replaced by an empty or **blank background** like there was never an image there.

I really have no idea why is this happening. In Eclipse the image shows normally and **I have tested my app in multiple devices and seems to be just fine.**

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here's where I set the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="226dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_green"
        android:onClick="onClick_login"
        android:text="@string/login_button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edit_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_username"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how u set background show relevant code

Comment: ur code is ok @carla

Comment: It should be because it works in most devices! I have only reported this error in LG G2 phone @kaushik

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea but not sure work,

1- use `LinearLayout` instead `RelativeLayout`

2- use dip for element height instead dp

Answer (score 0):

Place your images in drawable--xxhdpi. Android scales up/down the image for high/low resolution devices. It efficiently scales down the image but while scaling up it messes with memory issues. When you keep your image assets in high res drawable folder, it doesn't need to scale them up. Hope this helps.